# Category page masonry layout question

Tags: category, layout, grid-layout

I've been trying to work out how this masonry layout has been achieved;

I've tried Isotope masonry, but cannot work out how they have created this layout with different image sizes that seem randomised.

http://www.acnestudios.com/shop-men/

[image]